# Default values are used when the user just presses enter in standard input

Tags: io, fortran

My program requires standard input for some variables by user.

```
 subroutine stdInp(maxStep,gam,tolL)

 integer,intent(inout) :: maxStep
 real(dp),intent(inout) :: gam
 real(dp),intent(inout) :: tolL

 character :: tmpI

 write(*,*) "Max number of iterations?: "
 read(*,*) maxStep

 if (maxStep .le. 0 ) then
   write(*,*) "Invalid number of iterations!"
   stop
 end if

 (...)
```

I want to make the default values used when program user just press ENTER when they're required to input values.

I found similar questions from search, but they were not for Fortran.

How can I make Fortran code react to ENTER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read a string first. Then check if it contains a valid number or not.

```
 character(256) :: line

 write(*,*) "Max number of iterations?: "
 read(*,'(a)') line

 if (len_trim(line)==0) then
   maxStep = default_value
 else
   read(line, *, iostat = ierr) maxStep

   if (ierr/=0)  stop !or default
 end if
```

Comment: Good idea, though I would check for an empty string to take the default.  A mistyped number should not result in the default value.  You could also put it in a loop to reprompt for another entry to recover from the error.

Comment: Well, sure, but that is on the OP, not on me to set the exact condition. If you look in the original code he checks for negative numbers and stops. He can leave this check there too. Basically, this is not a code writing service, so the solutions are often not completely finalized working code.

Comment: I actually originally wanted to check *only* for the empty string. But that leaves invalid numbers unchecked. Whether they should leave to crash or the default, that is up to the OP.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for your considerate answer. I never thought that I can read line variable. It works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You have an answer which gives an approach for applying a default value in the case of invalid input.  In this answer I'll explain why pressing enter appears to do nothing.

With the list-directed input

```
read(*,*) maxStep
```

pressing enter without any other value simply ends the first input record.  However, with this style of input it doesn't actually return execution from the input statement: it is treated merely as a blank (as though a space was entered).  The input statement still waits for a value.

The answer reading into a string, you'll see, avoids list-directed input by using an explicit format (here `'(A)'`).  That's certainly viable.  An alternative is to use an integer-specific format

```
read(*,'(I10)') maxStep
```

If the pad-mode of the connection is `'YES'` then pressing enter to end the input record means the input field is all blanks, which is then interpreted as setting the value to zero.

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : input_unit
open(unit=input_unit, pad='YES')
read(*,'(I10)') maxStep
if (maxStep.eq.0) maxStep=default_maxStep
```

[Those first two lines are probably not necessary: the default for the pad mode is `'YES'`.]

This method also avoids using `iostat=` if you're happy leaving errors to be handled by termination.  You can of course use `iostat=` if you prefer.

Comment: It's really helpful. I think I understand how format specification works on IO statement more deeply.